# TextBox readonly propperty via readonly attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, readonly

Is there is differs between :

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "true");
```

and :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Is one of them has more advantage more of the other ?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason to do it in code rather than markup is if you want to change it at run time.